# Creating multidimensional array inside each

Tags: javascript

I want to create a multidimensional array from the values I retrieved on an ajax post request.

**API response**

`[{"id":"35","name":"IAMA","code":"24"},{"id":"23","name":"IAMB","code":"08"}]`

**jQuery code**

```
var mulArr = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/path/to/APIendpoint',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        codes: codes
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            mulArr[key]['id'] = value.code;
            mulArr[key]['text'] = value.name;
         });
    }
});
```

**Syntax error**

`TypeError: mulArr[key] is undefined`

I can properly fetch the `data` from the endpoint, the only error I encounter is the one I stated above. In perspective, all I want to do is simply a multidimensional array/object like this:

```
mulArr[0]['id'] = '24';
mulArr[0]['text'] = 'IAMA';
mulArr[1]['id'] = '08';
mulArr[1]['text'] = 'IAMB';
```

or

`[Object { id="24", text="IAMA"}, Object { id="08", text="IAMB"}]`

Comment: What does `console.log(key)` show when put within the `$.each`?

Comment: @Ian - It will output a numerical index `0 1`

Answer (score 2):

It happens because mulArr[0] is not an object, and mulArr[0]['id'] will throw that error. Try this:

```
var mulArr = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/path/to/APIendpoint',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        codes: codes
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            mulArr.push({id: parseInt(value.code), text: value.name});
            // or try this if select2 requires id to be continuous
            // mulArr.push({id: key, text: value.name});
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this mate, the error now works however, how can I make the multidimensional array into somewhat like this: `[Object { id="24", text="IAMA"}, Object { id="08", text="IAMB"}]`?

Comment: what's `Object { id="24", text="IAMA"}`?

Comment: That is my expected output, with your code above I constructed an array, how to turn it into something like that?

Comment: sorry i meant what's the difference between `{ id: "24", text: "IAMA" }` and `Object { id="24", text="IAMA"}`? note that the latter is not a valid javascript construct.

Comment: Because, seems that the Jquery select2 won't recognize my reconstructed array. It expects an input similar to that. This is the value `[Object { id="24", text="IAMA"}, Object { id="08", text="IAMB"}]` of the variable it can accept when I dump it to the `console.log`.

Comment: ahh i see. looking at select2's [documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array). it expects `id` to be an integer. see updated code

Comment: Exactly, it is the same documentation I am referring. Hmm. a character key is accepted on selected as I tried. (by modifying that `var data` on the sample). However, it doesn't really parse my input even if I tried your code.

Comment: I think the issue lies somewhere else then

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to using push (which is a cleaner approach) is to define the new object.

```
mulArr[key] = {
    id: value.code,
    text:value.name
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of achieving what you want would be this one:

```
var mulArr = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/path/to/APIendpoint',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        codes: codes
    },
    success: function(data) {
        mulArr = data.map(value => ({ id: parseInt(value.code), text: value.name }));
    }
});
```

This is cleaner and also uses builtin map instead of jQuery $.each. This way you also learn the benefits of using the map function (which returns a new array) and also learn useful features of ES2015.

If you cannot use ES6 (ES2015) here is another version:

```
mulArr = data.map(function (value) {
    return {
        id: parseInt(value.code),
        text: value.name
    };
});
```

I guess you can already see the advantages.

Comment: Thanks for this mate, the error now works however, how can I make the multidimensional array into somewhat like this: `[Object { id="24", text="IAMA"}, Object { id="08", text="IAMB"}]`?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia please log the response from the server (data in the callback) and then log mulArr after it has been assigned. Maybe this wil help up see where the problem lies